# How can I create an incremental sequence in Snowflake?

Tags: arrays, list, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence

I am trying to develop an array, a list or a sequence in Snowflake that has smaller increments than just moving by 1. So instead of creating something like:

```
SELECT seq4()
FROM table(generator(rowcount => 6))
```

That would display:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to be able set the steps or increments it moves between 1 and 5 by something like 0.01, so the result set would be:

```
0
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
.......
4.97
4.98
4.99
5
```

What would the best way to do this be? I am essentially trying to match a similar function to GENERATE_ARRAY in BigQuery where I can set the start, the end and the step sizes. Any ideas? Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lukasz answer is good, but as always, never use [SEQx](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html) if you want gap free values, because SEQ can have gaps, use [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html)

> This function uses sequences to produce a unique set of increasing integers, but does not necessarily produce a gap-free sequence. When operating on a large quantity of data, gaps can appear in a sequence. If a fully ordered, gap-free sequence is required, consider using the ROW_NUMBER window function.

```
SELECT (row_number()over(order by null)-1)/100
FROM table(generator(rowcount => 501));
```

### Array

And the ARRAY_AGG can put the values in any order, so if you want them "sorted" you should always use the ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(v) within group(order by v)
FROM (SELECT (row_number()over(order by null)-1)/100 as v
FROM table(generator(rowcount => 501)));
```

| ARRAY_AGG(V) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY V) |
| --- |
| [ 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, ... |

Answer (score 1):

The value could still be computed:

```
SELECT seq4()/100
FROM table(generator(rowcount => 501));
```

---

To get output as array:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(seq4()/100)
FROM table(generator(rowcount => 501));
```

> [
> 0,
> 0.01,
> 0.02,
> 0.03,
> 0.04,
> 0.05,
> 0.06,
> 0.07,
> 0.08,
> 0.09,
> 0.1,
> 0.11,
> 0.12,
> 0.13,
> ...
> 4.97,
> 4.98,
> 4.99,
> 5]